# Reading ports from pic18f, then do something

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic18

How can I read the first 2 bits from `PORTA` (`RA0`, `RA1`) and then work with them ? 
I have a switch connected to each one of them, and I want to output a `1` on `RB1` when both `RA0`, `RA1` are `1`.

I have configured `PORTA` as input and `PORTB` as output

```
MOVLW 0xF 
MOVWF TRISA,0 ;PORTA IN
```

And then in a loop, I continuously read `PORTA` values and I want to check if the two lowest bits are at `1`. To do so I compare value `PORTA` with `0x03` after moving `PORTA` to the WREG.

```
MOVF PORTA, 0, 0 ;W<--PORTA
CPFSLT 0x20, 0
MOVWF PORTB,0 ;PORTB<--W
```

In address `0x02` I have previously stored the value `0x03`

But it doesn't work, I don't know why.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

PORTA bits 0..3 are being configured as inputs but configuring PORTB pins as outputs is not shown. I/O pins are inputs at power up so you must explicitly make them outputs. You say you are continuously looping but don’t show a branch instruction after moving W into PORTB to loop back to read PORTA. And CPFSLT compares to whatever is in 0x20, you have stored 3 in 0x02.